# How to use microsoft authenticator with gmail

Tags: windows-10-mobile, nokia-lumia-1020

I can provide 2-step security for my FB account, but cant seem to do it with my Google account. How can i do it?

Comment: What problem exactly are you experiencing? The Microsoft Authenticator app supports Google accounts. Google might not list it in the list of auth apps, in that case just choose Google Authenticator, it makes no difference.

Comment: it worked thank you. i couldn't find any other app than google authenticator in the settings, thats y i was confused.